# client.on('message', message => {}) not catching DMs

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I am trying to make a bot that will be able to reply to DMs. I have seen online that:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    console.log(message)
})
```

will log the message from the DM.

But when I DM my bot it does not log the message, however, it does log normal messages. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You're doing nothing wrong, that should work as expected. Any error messages? Are you sure you message the correct bot? Is the bot logged in?

Comment: Maybe you could give some more context about your problem. It appears that you are trying to use some discord client for NodeJs that uses the same interface as event emitter API, but there are not any other info. Just your tags.

Answer (score -1):

First, you have to check if the user is typing in DM channel

```
if (message.channel.type === 'dm'){}
```

Now, you want to log the message

```
if (message.channel.type === 'dm'){ 
    console.log(`Author : ${message.author.username}\nContent : ${message.content}`);
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question. OP's handler isn't (apparently) being called for DMs, so how would checking the (non-existent) message fix things?